# Issue with displaying plots - using matplotlib in python

Tags: matplotlib, graph, display

I try to use `plt.show()` in python but I don't get result:

I'm doing this in a Jupyter notebook.

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/username/Desktop/Tesla.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], index_col='Date')
data.head()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()
ax.plot(data['Close'])
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Close')
plt.show()
```

I read that sometimes there are problems with displaying graphs when you add pandas and matplotlib library so I added additionaly - `pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()` but the graph isn't displayed and I don't see any error.

Comment: @JohanC I added code, this means that the graph isn't displayed

Comment: Did you try `%matplotlib inline` instead of `%matplotlib`. Or maybe `%matplotlib notebook` to get an interactive graph?

Comment: okay, with matplotib inline is working